# about chrome.tabs.executeScript( id,details, callback)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This function has a callback like `function(array of any result) {...};`

But I don't know what is the result means.

For example,

```
chrome.tabs..executeScript(null,
   {code:"var x = 10"},
   function(){});
```

how to return the `x` to the callback?

Comment: Look at [this question in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/Nco_o24bZ9A).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The result of a script is the last expression being evaluated. So in your example you could use:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"var x = 10; x"},
   function(results){ console.log(results); } );
```

This will log *[10]* to the extension's console.

*results* is actually an array of values because if the page has more than one frame you can specify that the script should be injected in each one of them and get the result of all injections. See the specification for [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). If you don't specify *allFrames: true*, then *results* will always be a single element array.

Comment: I have this `chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"var x = 10; x"}, function(results){ alert(results); } );` but gets undefined as an alert. Do you have any clue why this might happen?

Comment: @user1032613 that will happen if your extension doesn't have permissions to execute a script on the current tab. Make sure the domain is included in the `permissions` setting of your `manifest.json`

Comment: Thanks! And I just realized that, modifications made to manifest.json will only take effect after I reinstall the extension.

Comment: @user1032613 You can reload the extension by turning on the developer mode in chrome://extensions. or press ctrl-R

Comment: For me, the alert immediately disappears?

Comment: Note that the result will too be null if the code throws an error.

Comment: @virus No. You must be very careful with the code to be executed, if you want the results. Use `try..catch` and always return a `structured clonable` type (a string will do, an error won't)