# Chrome.tabs.executeScript callback function usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am reading [Chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) and do not known how to use the callback function of executeScript.

for example i have

```
function button(){
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {          
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js", allFrames: true}, function(results){
                for(var index in results){
                    console.log(results[index]);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

According to that page "result ( optional array of any ) The result of the script in every injected frame."

**Is this mean the callback is fired when content_script.js had executed in all injected page and frames? And How can I return a result from my content_script.js?**

Thanks.

**Answer:**
Find the answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166293/about-chrome-tabs-executescript-id-details-callback?rq=1), "The result of a script is the last expression being evaluated."

Comment: I assume you return a result by ending your script with a `return` statement.

Comment: No, it's simply the last expression evaluated. You don't actually return anything since the code passed via `code` or `file` isn't a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [about chrome.tabs.executeScript( id,details, callback)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166293/about-chrome-tabs-executescript-id-details-callback)