# How do I send tab ID at creating?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

So I want to create new tab and execute script on new tab and use variables from message sended earlier

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: myUrlblabla}, function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'myFileScript.js'}, function(Tab tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message.myVariable)
  })
});
```

And Chrome is saying that there is "unexpected identifier" in this line.

Comment: Try spacing this out on multiple lines.  "This line" is meaningless when it's all one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a syntax error (Tab tab). Try this code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: myUrlblabla
}, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'myFileScript.js'
  }, function(results) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message.myVariable);
  });
});
```

Comment: The method signature is also wrong. The callback of `chrome.tabs.create` should take an argument "tab"`, and `executeScript` should take `tab.id` instead of `null` (and its callback is invoked with the result of the script, not the tab, so remove `tab` from its callback).

Comment: Ok it is working now but I want to understand how it works. So I create a tab and then execute script on new tab and then I send message but what for is "results"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166293/about-chrome-tabs-executescript-id-details-callback

Comment: Yea but why do I need result of the script injected in the new tab?

Comment: You don't need to use it. It is optional. It is the result of the script in every injected frame. Just delete it if you don't need it.