# get all links in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that collecting social networks links from the web page where user is. So when user clicking button `getLinks` we get all links and then by checking condition passing them in the blocks of the extension. I tried to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, and get links through `urls = $$('a');` but it's not working

```
 $('#getLinks').click(function(e)
{
    var allLinks = [];
    var i = 0;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {"code": "urls = $$('a'); for (url in urls)
    { allLinks[i]=urls[url].href; i++;}"}, function() {
        var vk;
        var facebook;
        var linkedin;
        for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) 
        {
            var profil = (allLinks[i].href);
            if(profil.indexOf('vk.com')!=-1)
            {
                vk = profil;
                $('#vk').text(vk);
            }
            if(profilito.indexOf('facebook.com')!=-1)
            {
                facebook = profil;
                $('#fb').text(facebook);
            }
            if(profilito.indexOf('linkedin.com')!=-1)
            {
                linkedin = profil;
                $('#linkin').text(linkedin);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: in urls I'm getting null instead of the content that I'm getting in the console if I'm just will type urls = $$('a');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got an answer on my own question and posting here the solution

```
$('#getUser').click(function(e) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code: 'Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a")).map(a => a.innerHTML)'},function (results){
    var vk = [];
    var facebook = [];
    var linkedin = [];
    var allElements = results[0];
    for (var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) 
    {
    if (allElements[i].indexOf("https://vk.com") !== -1) 
    {
        vk.push (allElements[i]);
    }
    if (allElements[i].indexOf("https://facebook.com") !== -1 ) 
    {
        facebook.push (allElements[i]);
    }
    if (allElements[i].indexOf("https://www.linkedin.com") !== -1 ) 
    {
        linkedin.push (allElements[i]);
    }
    }
});
```

All links that we are finding on the page sorted in 3 arrays by belonging to the social networks

Comment: Finally! Good job! BTW shouldn't it be `map(a => a.href)`?

Comment: yup, I just misprinted and inserted piece from old code :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `executeScript` is used. That code can not access the variables `allLinks` and `i` because it is executed elsewhere. But you can make use of the returned value of that code like in this other SO [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13166293/9867451):

```
$('#getLinks').click(function(e) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {"code": "var urls = document.querySelectorAll('a'); for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { urls[i] = urls[i].href; }; urls"}, function(results) {
        var allLinks = results[0];

        // use allLinks here
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting null in results and in allLinks variable

Comment: I tried just to declare var x = 10; x in executeScript and it worked and transferred the value of 10 to results. But here it with urls it only gives me **null** value

Comment: @NikitaLvov Maybe the `$$` is causing that. AFAIK it is only available in dev tools. Try an alternative like `querySelectorAll`. Check my edit!

Comment: I tried yours with `querySelectorAll` and I tried to use `document.links` but it gives me now just empty object

Comment: @NikitaLvov Try injecting the code after document end using the [**`runAt`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) attribute.

Comment: Not working, IDK what else to try here. I'm even running it under `$(document).ready(function()` . The `document.links` as I said giving me empty object but the strange thing that `document.charset` for example works flawlessly. I suppose maybe it have limit to size?

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong and without an [MCVE](/help/mcve) it's hard to guess.

Comment: @NikitaLvov Try alerting or console logging the urls inside the injected code: `"...; alert(JSON.stringify(urls, null, 4)); urls"`. What are you getting?

Comment: if `{code: "var urls = document.querySelectorAll('a'); alert(JSON.stringify(urls, null, 4)); urls", runAt: "document_end"}` then I get empty object **{}** otherwise if `{code: "alert(JSON.stringify(urls, null, 4)); urls", runAt: "document_end"}` then I get **null**

Comment: @NikitaLvov Well... Maybe you're injecting the code into the wrong place. Try: `code: "alert(document.title);"` or `code: "alert(location.href);"` to see if the code is injected into the right document.

Comment: Location is fine, it's executed on the site and injected on it. I found the solution actually here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333782/chrome-tabs-executescript-is-not-returning-results-from-content-page) After 2 days of googling I found that **DOM nodes** cannot be returned as result using `executeScript`

Comment: Now I'm getting to another obstacle. When I'm trying to handle that array that full of objects collected from <a> tags it turning it into undefined array with length of 1

Comment: @NikitaLvov Can you post the new code, the one that kind of works?

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code: 'Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a")).map(a => a.innerHTML)'},function (results){
  console.log(results[0]);
     });
 });`

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code: 'Array.from(document.links).map(links => links.innerHTML)'},function (results){ console.log(results[0]); }); });` this work a bit better

Answer (score 0):

**Extract all URLs of any webpage**

**Step 1:** Run JavaScript code in Google Chrome Developer Tools
Open Google Chrome Developer Tools with Cmd + Opt + i (Mac) or F12 (Windows).
Click on the Console tab.
Copy-paste the following JavaScript code and press Enter.

```
const results = [
['Url', 'Anchor Text', 'External']
];
var urls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (urlIndex in urls) {
const url = urls[urlIndex]
const externalLink = url.host !== window.location.host
if(url.href && url.href.indexOf('://')!==-1) results.push([url.href, url.text, externalLink]) // url.rel
}
const csvContent = results.map((line)=>{
return line.map((cell)=>{
if(typeof(cell)==='boolean') return cell ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE'
if(!cell) return ''
let value = cell.replace(/[\f\n\v]*\n\s*/g, "\n").replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, ' ');
value = value.replace(/\t/g, ' ').trim();
return `"${value}"`
}).join('\t')
}).join("\n");
console.log(csvContent)
```

**Step 2:** Copy-paste exported URLs into a CSV file or spreadsheet tools

you will get

URL - The link URL
Anchor Text - The label associated with the link. Called "Anchor Text".
External - A boolean (TRUE, FALSE)

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/?trk=guest_homepage-basic_google-one-tap-submit